# python - string match only whole words

Tags: python

I have two lists - `query` and `line`. My code finds if a `query` such as:

```
["president" ,"publicly"]
```

Is contained in a `line` (order matters) such as:

```
["president" ,"publicly", "told"]
```

And this is the code I'm currently using:

```
if ' '.join(query) in ' '.join(line)
```

Problem is, I want to match whole words only. So the query below won't pass the condition statement:

```
["president" ,"pub"]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(' '.join(query)) + r'\b', ' '.join(line)) is not None
```

Comment: Might be worth `re.escape`'ing the query string

Comment: getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` after None

Comment: @Tom: What's after `None` (and before `re.search`)?

Comment: @Tom: You forgot the colon at the end of that `if`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regexes and the `\b` word boundaries:

```
import re
the_regex = re.compile(r'\b' + r'\b'.join(map(re.escape, ['president', 'pub'])) + r'\b')
if the_regex.search(' '.join(line)):
    print 'matching'
else:
    print 'not matching'
```

As an alternative you can write a function to check if a given list is a sublist of the line.  Something like:

```
def find_sublist(sub, lst):
    if not sub:
        return 0
    cur_index = 0
    while cur_index < len(lst):
        try:
            cur_index = lst.index(sub[0], cur_index)
        except ValueError:
            break

        if lst[cur_index:cur_index + len(sub)] == sub:
            break
        lst = lst[cur_index + 1:]
    return cur_index
```

Which you can use as:

```
if find_sublist(query, line) >= 0:
    print 'matching'
else:
    print 'not matching'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the "in" operator:

```
mylist = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

`'foo' in mylist` -> returns True
`'bar' in mylist` -> returns True
`'fo' in mylist` -> returns False
`'ba' in mylist` -> returns False

Comment: >>> 'foo bar' in mylist
False

Comment: of course... and of course: 'foo' in mylist and 'bar' in mylist -> True... so what? :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun you can also do:

```
a = ["president" ,"publicly", "told"]
b = ["president" ,"publicly"]
c = ["president" ,"pub"]
d = ["publicly", "president"]
e = ["publicly", "told"]

from itertools import izip
not [l for l,n in izip(a, b) if l != n] ## True
not [l for l,n in izip(a, c) if l != n] ## False
not [l for l,n in izip(a, d) if l != n] ## False
## to support query in the middle of the line:
try:
  query_list = a[a.index(e[0]):]
  not [l for l,n in izip(query_list, e) if l != n] ## True 
expect ValueError:
  pass
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [issubset](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset) method to achieve this. Simply do:

```
a = ["president" ,"publicly"]
b = ["president" ,"publicly", "told"]

if set(a).issubset(b):
    #bla bla
```

this will return matching items in both lists.

Comment: Reading the question I think order matters, and thus this would give wrong results in many situations.

Comment: The order matters so it can be a subset but not in the exact order

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `all` built in quantor function:

```
if all(word in b for word in a):
    """ all words in list"""
```

Note that this may not be run time efficient for long lists. Better use `set` type instead of list for `a` (list list of words to search in).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-regex way of doing it. I'm sure regex would be much faster than this:

```
>>> query = ['president', 'publicly']
>>> line = ['president', 'publicly', 'told']
>>> any(query == line[i:i+len(query)] for i in range(len(line) - len(query)))
True
>>> query = ["president" ,"pub"]
>>> any(query == line[i:i+len(query)] for i in range(len(line) - len(query)))
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicit is better than implicit. And as ordering matters, I would write it down like this:

```
query = ['president','publicly']
query_false = ['president','pub']
line = ['president','publicly','told']

query_len = len(query)
blocks = [line[i:i+query_len] for i in xrange(len(line)-query_len+1)]
```

`blocks` holds all relevant combinations to check for:

```
[['president', 'publicly'], ['publicly', 'told']]
```

Now you can simply check if your query is in that list:

```
print query in blocks # -> True
print query_false in blocks # -> False
```

The code works the way you would probably explain the straight forward solution in words, which is usually a good sign to me. If you have long lines and performance becomes a problem, you can replace the generated list by a generator.